# slidetransition appearence container in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, containers, slide

I need to make a container slide away in right direction from the screen and at the same time make another container slide in from the left side and stay in the center. It should happen after clicking continue.
I have tried SlideTransition Widget, but i have no idea, how to implement it, please help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bu0Au.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a `PageView`.
First define a page controller like this:
`final pageCtrlr = PageController();`

And don't forget to dispose it.

```
 @override
  void dispose() {
    pageCtrlr.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Define an `int` that keeps track of the current `Container`:
`int currentContainer = 0;`

Also define an `int` for the number of `Containers`:
`final int numberOfContainers = 10;`
For example I set if as 10. (That number should be the same as the number of children in your `PageView`)

Then add a `PageView` to your widget tree.

```
PageView(
controller: pageCtrlr, // assign your page controller to the page view
physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), // disables scrolling
children: <Widget>[...YourWidgets...],
onPageChanged: (int index) => setState(()=>currentContainer=index),
)
```

Then add this function as the `onPressed` on your button that changes the container.

```
void changeContainer(){
if (currentContainer + 1 > numberOfContainers - 1) return;

pageCtrlr.animateToPage(currentContainer + 1,
duration: Duration(miliseconds: 750), curve: Curves.linear,
// you can change the duration of the animation and curve
);
}
```